# I'm not sure why my code in C is giving me a segmentation fault at free, any ideas?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb, malloc

So this is my code which runs up till free(right); more like it completes merge sort then has an error, any solutions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void bubble_sort(int *l, int len) {
    // Iterate through the list
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // Iterate through the list
        for (int j = 0; j < len - 1; j++) {
            // If the current element is greater than the next element, swap them
            if (l[j] > l[j + 1]) {
                // Swap the elements
                int temp = l[j];
                l[j] = l[j + 1];
                l[j + 1] = temp;
                // Print the list
                for (int k = 0; k < len; k++) {
                    printf("%d ", l[k]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}

void selection_sort(int *l, int len) {
    // Iterate through the list
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // Set the minimum index to the current index
        int min_index = i;
        // Iterate through the list
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
            // If the current element is less than the minimum element, set the minimum index to the current index
            if (l[j] < l[min_index]) {
                min_index = j;
            }
        }
        // Swap the elements
        int temp = l[i];
        l[i] = l[min_index];
        l[min_index] = temp;
        // Print the list
        for (int k = 0; k < len; k++) {
            printf("%d ", l[k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void insertion_sort(int *l, int len) {
    // Iterate through the list
    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        // Set the current index to the current index
        int j = i;
        // While the current index is greater than 0 and the previous element is greater than the current element, swap them
        while (j > 0 && l[j - 1] > l[j]) {
            // Swap the elements
            int temp = l[j - 1];
            l[j - 1] = l[j];
            l[j] = temp;
            // Decrement the current index
            j--;
        }
        // Print the list
        for (int k = 0; k < len; k++) {
            printf("%d ", l[k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void merge(int *left, int left_len, int *right, int right_len) {
    // Create a new list
    int *result = malloc((left_len + right_len) * sizeof(int));
    // Set the left index to 0 and the right index to 0
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    // While the left index is less than the length of the left list and the right index is less than the length of the right list
    while (i < left_len && j < right_len) {
        // If the left element is less than or equal to the right element, append the left element to the result list and increment the left index
        if (left[i] <= right[j]) {
            result[i + j] = left[i];
            i++;
        }
        // Else, append the right element to the result list and increment the right index
        else {
            result[i + j] = right[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    // Append the remaining elements in the left list to the result list
    for (int k = i; k < left_len; k++) {
        result[k + j] = left[k];
    }
    // Append the remaining elements in the right list to the result list
    for (int k = j; k < right_len; k++) {
        result[k + i] = right[k];
    }
    // Print the result list
    for (int k = 0; k < left_len + right_len; k++) {
        printf("%d ", result[k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    // Copy the result list to the original list
    for (int k = 0; k < left_len + right_len; k++) {
        left[k] = result[k];
    }
    // Free the result list
    free(result);
}
void merge_sort(int *l, int len) {
    // If the list is empty or has one element, return the list
    if (len <= 1) {
        return;
    }
    // Set the middle index to the length of the list divided by 2
    int mid = len / 2;
    // Set the left list to the first half of the list
    int *left = malloc(mid * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
        left[i] = l[i];
    }
    // Set the right list to the second half of the list
    int *right = malloc((len - mid) * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = mid; i < len; i++) {
        right[i - mid] = l[i];
    }
    // Sort the left list
    merge_sort(left, mid);
    // Sort the right list
    merge_sort(right, len - mid);
    // Merge the left list and the right list
    merge(left, mid, right, len - mid);
    // Free the left list and the right list
    free(left);
    free(right);                                       //Error ln 142, in picture below
}

int binary_search(int *l, int len, int target) {
    // Set the low index to 0 and the high index to the length of the list minus 1
    int low = 0;
    int high = len - 1;
    // While the low index is less than or equal to the high index
    while (low <= high) {
        // Set the middle index to the sum of the low index and the high index divided by 2
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        // If the middle element is equal to the target, return the middle index
        if (l[mid] == target) {
            return mid;
        }
        // Else if the middle element is less than the target, set the low index to the middle index plus 1
        else if (l[mid] < target) {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        // Else, set the high index to the middle index minus 1
        else {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
    }
    // If the target is not found, return -1
    return -1;
}

int main() {
    // Create a list
    int l[] = {17, 36, 3, 10, 29, 42, 34, 8};
    int len = sizeof(l) / sizeof(l[0]);
    // Print the list
    printf("Bubble Sort:\n");
    // Sort the list using bubble sort
    bubble_sort(l, len);
    // Print the list
    printf("Selection Sort:\n");
    // Sort the list using selection sort
    selection_sort(l, len);
    // Print the list
    printf("Insertion Sort:\n");
    // Sort the list using insertion sort
    insertion_sort(l, len);
    // Print the list
    printf("Merge Sort:\n");
    // Sort the list using merge sort
    merge_sort(l, len);
    // Print the list
    printf("Binary Search:\n");
    // Search for the target in the list using binary search
    printf("%d\n", binary_search(l, len, 42));
    return 0;
}
```

So I rewrote the code from python to C, and debugging in GDB gives me the error in the screenshot.

[GDB ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9KRY.png)

I've tried to edit the function itself to rectify the memory issue but it wouldn't work so i reverted back to this and hope someone has some more insight.

Comment: You've corrupted your heap somewhere prior to your call to `free()`, either with something like a double `free()` or a buffer overrun that overwrote some important internal heap data used to keep track of heap memory use.  The code that corrupted the heap laid a land mine that the call to `free()` stepped on.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I assumed as much, I am just not sure where which seems to be my new issue :( I am still looking through, thank you for the reply

Comment: You have at least one buffer overflow. https://godbolt.org/z/dEYofracK When you fix the first one don't be surprised if another pops right up.

Comment: @MyraKhan The error could be anywhere - even in code totally unrelated to where you're getting errors.  Tools like [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) are invaluable in finding the problems.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Appreciate it, I do see that it's now pulling up lots of memory issues.

Comment: removing the free from free(right);  worked

Comment: I don't think that is the resolution.  valgrind doesn't like `for (int k = 0; k < left_len + right_len; k++) {
  left[k] = result[k];
 }
`

Comment: You should use `size_t`and not `int` for sizes

Answer (score 2):

The segfault is triggered in `merge()` used by `merge_sort()`.  Everything else is irrelevant.

In `merge_sort()` you copy half of the input array `l` into a newly allocated array `left` and the other half into another newly allocated array `right`.  Then recursively `merge_sort()` those two halves which is fine.  To combine the two halves `merge()` is called where you incorrectly assume that the left and right arrays are allocated consecutively:

```
    for (int k = 0; k < left_len + right_len; k++) {
        left[k] = result[k];
    }
```

The minimal fix is to make the assumption valid:

```
void merge_sort(int *l, int len) {
    if (len <= 1) {
        return;
    }
    int mid = len / 2;
    int *left = malloc(len * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
        left[i] = l[i];
    }
    int *right = left + mid;
    for (int i = mid; i < len; i++) {
        right[i - mid] = l[i];
    }
    merge_sort(left, mid);
    merge_sort(right, len - mid);
    merge(left, mid, right, len - mid);
    free(left);
}
```

A even better resolution would be to:

1. Strictly separate the code under test and your test harness.  In this case you want to delegate to `main()` the task of duplicating the input array instead of doing that in your sort algorithm.  This allows `merge_sort()` to operate on the input array in-place (`merge()` still uses the temporary array).
2. Eliminate the `right` array pointer argument to `merge()`.  This documents that the left and right arrays are part of the the same array.
3. Refactor the `merge()` and `merge_sort()` interface so the length argument is before the array argument so you can document how they relate.
4. (Not fixed).  You could allocate the temporary space needed for merging once in `merge_sort()` and pass it to `merge_sort2()` and `merge2()`.  That way you only have `O(n)` space overhead instead of `O(n*log(n))`.  It is worth pointing out that `malloc()` may require a kernel context switch which in turn would be the most expensive operation th the `merge()` + `merge_sort()` implementation.  Doing 1 instead of n*log(n) calls to `malloc()` could be a significant (constant) factor in run-time.  Sharing the temporary space, however, comes a cost as you would no longer be able to do the otherwise non-overlapping merge sorts in parallel.
5. Prefer the type `size_t` to `int` for lengths.  sizeof() in particular returns a `size_t` value, and the cast to the (signed) `int` will be problematic for sizes greater than `INTMAX`.
6. Prefer `memcpy()` instead of explicit loops when possible.  `memcpy()` is highly optimized, and succinctly expresses intent.
7. Prefer passing a variable instead of a type to `sizeof()`.  The former is robust if you change the type of the variable where the latter requires a code change if you didn't use a `typedef` for the type.
8. Finally, I added a `print()` function so you don't need the debug print statements in the sorting functions themselves.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void merge(size_t left_len, size_t right_len, int l[left_len + right_len]) {
    int *result = malloc((left_len + right_len) * sizeof(*l));
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i < left_len && j < right_len) {
        if (l[i] <= l[left_len + j]) {
            result[i + j] = l[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            result[i + j] = l[left_len + j];
            j++;
        }
    }
    memcpy(result + i + j, l + i, (left_len - i) * sizeof(*l));
    memcpy(result + left_len + j, l + left_len + j, (right_len - j) * sizeof(*l));
    memcpy(l, result, (left_len + right_len) * sizeof(*l));
    free(result);
}

void merge_sort(size_t len, int l[len]) {
    if (len < 2) return;
    int mid = len / 2;
    merge_sort(mid, l);
    merge_sort(len - mid, l + mid);
    merge(mid, len - mid, l);
}

void print(size_t len, int a[len]) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%d%s", a[i], i + 1 < len ? ", " : "\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int l[] = {17, 36, 3, 10, 29, 42, 34, 8};
    size_t len = sizeof(l) / sizeof(*l);
    int l2[len];
    memcpy(l2, l, sizeof(l));
    merge_sort(len, l2);
    print(len, l2);
}
```

and it returns:

```
3, 8, 10, 17, 29, 34, 36, 42
```

valgrind is happy:

```
ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```